# FadeIn and FadeOut fire in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here i have two divs with video and text, when i click on next invention second video should show. It works perfectly but its it showing from bottom, i need it to be happen from the same place where first div is hiding

```js
$('#next_invention').click(function() {
  $('#video_1').fadeOut(500);
  $('#video_2').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div id="video_1">
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <div class="col-md-12 normal_desc_grey_ans embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="640" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fPgCbkDcUao?autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-head"><b>Arjun rai hated the malai on the milk</b></p>
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-text">So he created a vibrating coaster<br/>That comes underneath the glass</p>
          <div style="text-align:center;margin:40px 0;">
            <div class="normal_desc_grey_ans" style="text-align:left;">
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button id="next_invention" class="bbd-btn">Next Invention</button></p><br/>
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button class="bbd-btn">I want my child to experience this</button></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video_2" style="display:none;">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <div class="col-md-12 normal_desc_grey_ans embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="640" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pcrWVrUhdLU?autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-head"><b>Arjun rai hated the malai on the milk</b></p>
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-text">So he created a vibrating coaster<br/>That comes underneath the glass</p>
          <div style="text-align:center;margin:40px 0;">
            <div class="normal_desc_grey_ans" style="text-align:left;">
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button id="next_invention" class="bbd-btn">Next Invention</button></p><br/>
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button class="bbd-btn">I want my child to experience this</button></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to place your divs using absolute positioning

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj What does this have to do with having a delay between the two animations?

Comment: @chsdk When I checked this question first, it asked to fadeIn/fadeOut divs at same place, not same time.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Ah ok you are right about that too, it's misleading :)

Answer (score 2):

The [**.fadeOut()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) method accepts a second argument, a function to execute when the animation is complete:

> `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`
>
> **duration (default: 400)**
>
> Type: Number or String
>
> A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> **complete**
>
> Type: Function()
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per
>   matched element.

So the appropriate way to call the `fadeIn()` function when the `fadeOut()` animation is complete, is to use a callback function in the second argument, so it will execute when the animation is complete.

Your code will be:

```
$('#next_invention').click(function() {
  $('#video_1').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#video_2').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('#next_invention').click(function() {
  $('#video_1').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#video_2').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div id="video_1">
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <div class="col-md-12 normal_desc_grey_ans embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="640" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fPgCbkDcUao?autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-head"><b>Arjun rai hated the malai on the milk</b></p>
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-text">So he created a vibrating coaster<br/>That comes underneath the glass</p>
          <div style="text-align:center;margin:40px 0;">
            <div class="normal_desc_grey_ans" style="text-align:left;">
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button id="next_invention" class="bbd-btn">Next Invention</button></p><br/>
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button class="bbd-btn">I want my child to experience this</button></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video_2" style="display:none;">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <div class="col-md-12 normal_desc_grey_ans embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="640" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pcrWVrUhdLU?autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-head"><b>Arjun rai hated the malai on the milk</b></p>
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-text">So he created a vibrating coaster<br/>That comes underneath the glass</p>
          <div style="text-align:center;margin:40px 0;">
            <div class="normal_desc_grey_ans" style="text-align:left;">
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button id="next_invention" class="bbd-btn">Next Invention</button></p><br/>
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button class="bbd-btn">I want my child to experience this</button></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `delay()` can help you. This will show 2nd video after 1st has been hidden.

```
$('#video_2').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
```

```js
$('#next_invention').click(function() {
  $('#video_1').fadeOut(500);
  $('#video_2').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div id="video_1">
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <div class="col-md-12 normal_desc_grey_ans embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="640" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fPgCbkDcUao?autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-head"><b>Arjun rai hated the malai on the milk</b></p>
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-text">So he created a vibrating coaster<br/>That comes underneath the glass</p>
          <div style="text-align:center;margin:40px 0;">
            <div class="normal_desc_grey_ans" style="text-align:left;">
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button id="next_invention" class="bbd-btn">Next Invention</button></p><br/>
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button class="bbd-btn">I want my child to experience this</button></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video_2" style="display:none;">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <div class="col-md-12 normal_desc_grey_ans embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="640" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pcrWVrUhdLU?autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-offset-0 col-center-block placeholder" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-head"><b>Arjun rai hated the malai on the milk</b></p>
          <p class="bbd-sub-min-text">So he created a vibrating coaster<br/>That comes underneath the glass</p>
          <div style="text-align:center;margin:40px 0;">
            <div class="normal_desc_grey_ans" style="text-align:left;">
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button id="next_invention" class="bbd-btn">Next Invention</button></p><br/>
              <p class="large text-muted" style="margin-top:15px;text-align:left;"><button class="bbd-btn">I want my child to experience this</button></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Abhishek Pandey answer:

You should use the complete Callback and not a delay:

```
$('#next_invention').click(function() {
  $('#video_1').fadeOut(500,function(){
     $('#video_2').fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```